# What Does "that for" mean?

Tags: poetry

I'm trying to grasp the specific meaning of this poem. I get the sentiment, but have a hard time grasping *that for destruction ice* in this context. The author knows enough of hate to make a statement about something that is also great, but what is that statement really? What is referenced?

> Some say the world will end in fire,
>   Some say in ice.
>   From what I've tasted of desire
>   I hold with those who favor fire.
>   But if it had to perish twice,
>   I think I know enough of hate
>   To say that for destruction ice
>   Is also great
>   And would suffice.

Comment: Consider the sentence _For destruction ice is also great._ That's the tensed clause introduced by _that_. The sequence "that for" doesn't mean anything; it's not a constituent. _That_ introduces the subordinate clause, and _for_ introduces the prepositional phrase _for destruction_, and they both occur at the beginning of the clause, in that order. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take it out of the poem's format to analyse it:

> I think I know enough of hate to say that **for** destruction ice is also great.

We can replace *for* with *to cause*:

> I think I know enough of hate to say that **to cause** destruction, ice is also great.

Adding a comma after *destruction* helps understand the grammar. So now we can analyse *to cause destruction, ice is also great* as:

> Ice is also a great method of (causing) destruction.

Comment: Aha, the meter made it hard to parse for me. I'm not native in english...